# Server CPU goes 100% in 2 hours on Django WSGI Server on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, wsgi

I have django rest api application hosted on Elastic Beanstalk.
I am seeing my server going up by 90% with C4.large instance.

I have close to 1500/min sum requests being processed at any point of time.
I have been trying to figure it out but not able to find whats going wrong.

I have my DRF API + Celery Worker code base under one project.
I extensively use pandas on my workers but not on DRF endpoints.

Does having many requirements affect WSGI Server.

```
amqp==1.4.7
anyjson==0.3.3
awscli==1.7.42
Babel==2.1.1
backports-abc==0.4
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
billiard==3.3.0.21
boto3==1.1.1
botocore==1.1.12
celery==3.1.19
colorama==0.3.3
Django==1.8
django-braces==1.8.1
django-cors-headers==1.1.0
django-debug-toolbar==1.4
django-loaderio==0.3.0
django-oauth-toolkit==0.9.0
djangorestframework==3.1.3
docutils==0.12
flower==0.8.3
futures==2.2.0
google==1.7
greenlet==0.4.9
gunicorn==19.4.5
httplib2==0.9.2
jmespath==0.7.1
keen==0.3.20
kombu==3.0.30
livestreamer==1.12.2
Markdown==2.6.2
oauthlib==1.0.3
Padding==0.4
pubnub==3.7.4
pyasn1==0.1.8
pycrypto==2.6.1
PyMySQL==0.6.6
python-dateutil==2.4.2
pytz==2015.7
PyYAML==3.11
redis==2.10.5
requests==2.8.0
rsa==3.1.4
six==1.9.0
sqlparse==0.1.18
tornado==4.3
virtualenv==13.1.2
webapp2==2.5.2
eventlet==0.18.4
python-gcm==0.4
numpy==1.11.0
pandas==0.18.0
py2neo==2.0.8
neo4jrestclient==2.1.1
google-api-python-client==1.5.1
python-firebase==1.2
cassandra-driver==3.4.1
passlib==1.6.5
django-request-logging==0.4.6
django-cache-machine==0.9.1
genderize==0.1.5
logentries==0.17
psutil==4.3.1
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: There are various stuff done
1. option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "xxxxx.settings.production"
    PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/xxxxx:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "xxxx/wsgi.py"
    NumProcesses: 2
    NumThreads: 10

2. We were syncing data using serializers. So we save our serializers in the mongodb for faster fetch.